# cant display 3rd item on json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at gettodo (script.js:4)
>       at script.js:13

No one can fix my error problem. The entire HTML file is here:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <div id="3rd_title_here"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

entire script.js code here

```
function gettodo() {
    var TODOS ='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        url: TODOS,
        success: function(data) {  
          $('#3rd_title_here').html(data[2].title);
        }
    });
}
setInterval(gettodo(),1000);
```

im just trying to display the 3rd title on the json

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}, {
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 2,
  "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
  "completed": false
},{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 3,
  "title": "fugiat veniam minus", // <--- im trying to display this guy
  "completed": false
}
```

Comment: `$` is a reference to jQuery, so you need to include jquery.js in your page *before* your own script. See the duplicate for more information

Comment: You have jQuery included?

Comment: OMG IT WORKED!!!!!!!! thx alot!! XD THX i feel soo dumb now hahaha